# APNS throws error "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"

Tags: ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm getting this exception "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception", with the inner exception "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"

when trying to call this method:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(apsHost, certs, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);
```

I'm using the production certificate and calling the production APNS server ("gateway.push.apple.com") at port 2195.

I know there are several posts on this (most are old) but I really tried everything that I found on other posts and different searches on google, nothing is working for my issue.

most of the answers I found was to change the SSL protocol from Ssl3 to Tls, so I did that and it didn't work.

also tried to recreate the push service certificate from apple with xcode, and reinstalling it.

I'll appreciate your help if anyone have any idea what else I missed

this is the rest of the code:

```
private void PushIosNotification(object notificationData)
    {
        Log.Get().Info(Log.BuildMessageEx(notificationData));
        SslStream sslStream = null;
        TcpClient tcpClient = null;
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        BinaryWriter bw = null;
        try
        {
            NotificationData nData = (NotificationData)notificationData;
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            if (certs != null)
            {
                certs.Add(getServerCert(nData.AppleProductionPushCertificateFriendlyName, nData.AppleDevelopmentPushCertificateFriendlyName, nData.IsProduction));

                string apsHost = certs[0].ToString().Contains("Production") ? nData.AppleServerURL : nData.AppleSandBoxServerURL;


                tcpClient = new TcpClient(apsHost, int.Parse(nData.AppleServerPort));

                sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());

                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(apsHost, certs, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];

                ms = new MemoryStream();
                bw = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

                bw.Write(new byte[] { 0, 0, 32 });
                bw.Write(hexToData(nData.DeviceId));
                bw.Write((byte)0);

                // Create the APNS payload - new.caf is an audio file saved in the application bundle on the device
                string msg = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + nData.Message.Replace("₪", "&#8362;").Replace("ש\"ח", "&#8362;") + "\",\"badge\":" + nData.IBadge + ",\"sound\":\"new.caf\",\"url\":\"www.google.com\"}}";

                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] postBytes = encoding.GetBytes(msg);

                // Write the data out to the stream
                bw.Write((byte)postBytes.Length);
                bw.Write(postBytes);
                bw.Flush();

                sslStream.Write(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException CrEx)
        {
            Log.Get().Error("CryptographicException ConnectToAPNS1:", CrEx);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Get().Error("PushIosNotification", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tcpClient != null)
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
            if (sslStream != null)
            {
                sslStream.Close();
            }
            if (ms != null)
            {
                ms.Close();
            }
            if (bw != null)
            {
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK now it's working, did nothing except creating a console application with the same code, it worked there and then the original code start to work also..